# UIPageViewController with UITableView, swipe to remove cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with an `UITableView`, and the `UIViewController` resides in a `UIPageViewController`. In fact, I have a bunch of these residing in the `UIPageViewController`, and I swipe in order to see the next/previous `UIViewController` which is all working as intended. However, I also need to be able to remove the `UITableViewCell's` in the `UITableView` by swiping, and it seems that the `UIPageViewController` takes complete precedence over the swipe, making it impossible for me to remove my cells.

How do I solve this? I assume there is not easy straightforward way, since there never is, so any suggestions? If you're posting code please do so in Swift, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how you are going to make the left swipe do two things. You could add a button to put the table into edit mode and delete rows that way.

Comment: i agree with @ryantxr an edit button is the best way to go heres

Comment: @ClockWise What did you do in the end ? Did you try my solution ?

Comment: @Coder1000 I haven't fully decided what to do yet, that's why I've been absent here. I fixed it temporarily by not using the PageControllers delegate at all and call setViewControllers myself depending on swipe on the upper part of my view. Basically you swipe between controllers by swiping, unless you swipe on a cell which triggers remove cell instead. But it's very...stale. So I think I'll go with the editing button suggestion, but it must be discussed with my employer first :)

Comment: @ClockWise Ok ! Was my answer helpful or not ? If it won't get accepted, I prefer to delete it. Please let me know :)

Comment: @Coder1000 marked as accepted, I will use this approach. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ClockWise Glad I could help in some way ! :D

Comment: You can't make one gesture recognizer do two things, but you can make swipe left do two things. My app has a `UITableView` in a `UIPageViewController` that allows swipe to delete in cells that can be deleted, but allows paging to occur everywhere else. You should check out the 3 WWDC videos on scrolling from 2012-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to make the left swipe do two things.

The best solution would be to create an edit button that makes delete buttons appear next to your cells, like this:

[image]

The edit transforms into "Done" when tapped to remove the  "delete mode".

An alternate way to do this would be to create a specific zone on your screen where the left swipe brings another VC, so you can use the rest of your screen to use left swipe on your elements to delete them.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can't make one gesture recognizer do two things, but you can make swipe left do two things. My app has a `UITableView` in a `UIPageViewController` that allows swipe to delete in cells that can be deleted, but allows paging to occur everywhere else. You should check out the 3 WWDC videos on scrolling from 2012-2015

Comment: @jjatie, I am stuck on tableview cell swipe action when inside UIPageViewController. Can you tell me the approach you used as you said which allowed you to allow swipe to delete in cells that can be deleted, but allows paging to occur everywhere else ?

Comment: I ended up making my own PageViewController

Comment: @jjatie Could you maybe explain how you did it?

Comment: @CodyMace you can start with the Apple demo app "PageControl: Using a Paginated UIScrollView" You use this to get memory management for free and then add your own gesture recognizers so you can control which get passed to the table view.